# Add Items Step by Step to a listbox using anything? (not all at once but step by step)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Can Any body show me an example, how to add items one-by-one (not all at once) to a listbox, that is after the page load event is done, this code should add 0 to 4 to a list box step by step not all at once, which is the case now.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<5,i++)
{
listbox1.items.add(i.Tostring());
}
```

What this code does is that, it shows 0,1,2,3,4 all at once when page load is complete. I want it to show 0, then 1, then 2 and so on. (My problem is similar to this one so solving this would greatly help me).

EDIT: It's not necessary that elements should be added to a listbox, it can be anything textbox field, etc (I heard ajax calls are not possible from listbox, so just incase)

Comment: Similar to _which_ one? What do you want to achieve? What does _"show 0, then 1, then 2 and so on"_ mean??

Comment: Kindly elaborate a little bit, what do you mean by step by step? You want to show 0 than after some delay 1 than 2, is it so?

Comment: does u want progress bar after each add

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I mean that this isn't exactly my problem (I want to add markers on google map, one by one and show them), but that would make the question really complex. So I came up with an analogy.
Simply I want to SHOW integers (0,1,2,3,4) BEING added to a list box in my webpage.

Comment: @Imran Balouch , YES sir, almost right but in my exact problem(the listbox is an analogy) I'm fetching the value of item from another website, so I don't want to add MANUAL delay, the urlopen instruction itself adds delay on each iteration.

What I want to do is "to show these elements BEING ADDED", not all at once as mentioned above(asp.net execute all instructions in .cs file and shows them all at once), So it should first add 0 to the listbox, then add 1 to listbox, then 2 and so on at time when the listbox1.items.add(i), instruction is being executed.

Comment: @Nikhil No, I simply want to show items as they are added and not after all instructions in .cs file have been executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i<5,i++)
{
listbox1.items.add(i.Tostring());
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Something like this ?

Edit : 5000 equals to 5 seconds, so change it as you want it.

Comment: No not exactly, what is does is that, once you run the program it takes (5x5=25 secs). and then shows a listbox with elements from 0 to 4.
I want to show elements AS THEY ARE BEING ADDED, like firt lisbox should show only 0, then after 5 secs, it should show 0 & 1, then after 5 secs, 0,1 & 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

In your case you will have to add items asynchronously or through client side, as you are adding them synchronously so from server side they are added and when the page is rendered they are all in the page.

Infact you should go for client side approach to bring this effect, from server side you won't be able to do it.